# writing regular text in complex math expression in latex

Tags: latex

Right now I'm writing this expression where I would like to have the term "net" text.. and not italics, otherwise it implies n*e*t.. I don't know how to do this.. can someone help me fix my latex expression here:

```
f_i^{s*}(net_i(t)) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\tanh(\lambda net_i(t))
```

Ted

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\text{net}_i`.

Answer (score 0):

If your LaTeX distribution does not know the command `\text`, try `\mbox{net}_i`